# facebook graph can not get comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After Search post from graph

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&fields=from,message,picture,link,name,caption,comments,description,created_time,id&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX`

here will return some data. In the third post:

```
     "from": {
        "name": "Alessio Mrbillyplus Frustaci",
        "id": "1665626783"
     },
     "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDGoBK_lUeeMb5x&w=130&h=130&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi3.ytimg.com\u00252Fvi\u00252Fjo5GcYeh7XA\u00252Fdefault.jpg",
     "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo5GcYeh7XA&feature=share",
     "name": "Herbie Hancock \"Watermelon Man\"",
     "caption": "www.youtube.com",
     "description": "From the 1973 album \"Headhunters\" here's Herbie Hancock with \"Watermelon Man\" Sampled by Super Cat \" Dolly My Baby\" LL Cool J \"1-900-LL Cool J\" Shaquille O'N...",
     "created_time": "2011-09-17T17:44:48+0000",
     "id": "1665626783_235117223205324",
     "comments": {
        "data": [
           {
              "id": "1665626783_235117223205324_3043725",
              "from": {
                 "name": "Alessio Mrbillyplus Frustaci",
                 "id": "1665626783"
              },
              "message": "La enne e la doppia effe aaaaaa",
              "created_time": "2011-09-17T17:45:52+0000"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
```

It is clearly that it has comments in it. So the `PostID` is `1665626783_235117223205324` and `CommentID` is `1665626783_235117223205324_3043725`? But when I tried search a `post` or `comments`, the data return empty.

`https://graph.facebook.com/1665626783_235117223205324?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX`//empty

`https://graph.facebook.com/1665626783_235117223205324/comments?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX`//empty

`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?
callback=json&
query=SELECT%20comments%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%20%3D%20'1665626783_235117223205324'&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX` //empty

What is the big problem?

Comment: Could we not use actual people facebook ids? I don't want to post a link... but yeah, it's an actual person with a public profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be privacy settings in place which prevent the current user from seeing the posts or comments, where are those comments posted? Are you accessing them with an access_token from a user who can see the content?

As Mahima said, both of those calls should be working and i've tested equivalent calls with posts from my own news feed or page walls.

A call to `/1665626783_235117223205324` for me returns false, which indicates i don't have permission to view the item.

This could also be a bug, but you'd need to have a very clear set of sample data to demonstrate the issue so it can be reproduced by Facebook

Comment: I also can see my post and comment. but not others, maybe this is a bug. still waiting something, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with post id and comment id both as

http://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_OR_POST_ID?access_token=APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN

both are working .. 
Make sure the access_token you are using is either of the application which you used for posting on a user's wal.. Or the access_token has sufficient read_stream and offline_access permission of the user ..

Comment: still not work, test in `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer` put the full `access_token`, select `read_stream and offline_access`.

Comment: Make a curl call to this URL to get your Application's access_token ../* Fetching App Token */
$url = FACEBOOK_GRAPH_S."/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FACEBOOK_APP_ID."&client_secret=".FACEBOOK_SECRET."&grant_type=client_credentials";